# Warning: Failed to load http://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js (ignore) for generating graph using laravel snappy

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-snappy

We are using the laravel snappy to generate the pdf with graph using google library. When we generate the pdf at the moment it shows error as:

```
[2022-09-07 10:12:32] local.ERROR: The exit status code '-1073741819' says something went wrong:
stderr: "Loading pages (1/6)
[>                                                           ] 0%
[======>                                                     ] 10%
[========>                                                   ] 14%
Warning: Failed to load http://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js (ignore)
"
stdout: ""
command: C:\"Program Files"\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf --lowquality --enable-javascript --javascript-delay "1200000" --enable-smart-shrinking --no-stop-slow-scripts "C:\Users\santosh\AppData\Local\Temp\knp_snappy63186e90573620.16051650.html" "C:\Users\santosh\AppData\Local\Temp\knp_snappy63186e90578264.77645537.pdf".
```

The controller code is as below:

```
        try{
            $render = view('graph')->render();
   
            $pdf = \PDF::loadView('graph');
            $pdf->setOption('enable-javascript', true);
            $pdf->setOption('javascript-delay', 1200000);
            $pdf->setOption('enable-smart-shrinking', true);
            $pdf->setOption('no-stop-slow-scripts', true);
            return $pdf->download('graph.pdf');

        }catch(Exception $e){
            Log::error($e->getMessage());
        }
```

Tried multiple things but noithing seems to be working. Anyone please help me with same.